# Compilation fails with any table option

Tags: errors, undefined

I have I problem that I fail to debug. It happens, but disappears after additional compilations. I cannot find out which minimal code produces it because I cannot reproduce it. The code I load is my latex template which is much too huge to show here. Currently I changed a lot to support lualatex, but the error also happened in 2015, but at that time I did not try to find the origin.

```
Undefined control sequence.
\@@FBset@ ->\global \c@FBcntd
l.27 \begin{table}[h]
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def’ed.
```

Any idea in which package this code exits? That would help me to debug it further.
I compile with latest texlive on windows with lualatex. But I know that it was found in my code already in 2015 with pdflatex.

EDIT: I could find the code in the aux file

```
\gdef\@@FBset@{\global\c@FBcnta}
```

But still do not know how it gets there.

EDIT: Due to the information that it is a code from floatrow I could find a MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup{%
    style=plain,%
    facing=yes, % different layout for even and odd pages if twoside is on
}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{alph}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[h]
\end{table}     

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could at the very least post a typical preamble...

Comment: `\@@FBset@` is from the floatrow package, and the error means that some counter is not defined. You could try `\newcounter{FBcnta}`  (or `\newcounter{FBcntd}`).

Comment: actually floatrow contains `\FR@iffacing{\FB@writeaux{\string\global\string\c@FBcnt\thepage}}\relax`, which probably means that you are confusing it somewhere by setting the page numbering to alph.

Comment: Indeed, I am using `\pagenumbering{alph}\pagestyle{empty}`. Is floatrow still maintained and supported? Or is there a newer alternative available? The package documentation is from 2009.

Comment: why do you set the pagenumbering to alph, if the style is empty?

Comment: I have not even thought about that. It was probably a code taken from a different page and copied and changed. The error dissappears when `\pagenumbering{alph}` is removed.

Comment: but just to be clear: it is a bug/a restriction  of `floatrow` that it assumes that `\thepage`  to expand to a number.

Comment: If I remove `\pagenumbering{alph}`I get another error
`! Package pageslts Error: pagenumbering scheme missing.?`
Can the floatrow error be fixed after loading the package? There is no maintainer defined..